# Symfony 2 form Handle request not found

Tags: php, symfony, controller, request, handle

I am making an form in symfony 2 controller.

Here is what it looks like:

```
    $data = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');



    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()

        ->add('incident', 'entity', array('class' => 'MainCoreBundle:Incidenttype', 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => true))
        ->add('date', 'text',array('data'=>$data))
        ->add('time', 'text',array('data'=>$time))
        ->getForm();

   $form->handleRequest($request);



    if ($form->isValid())

        if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()

        ->setSubject('SUBJECT')
        ->setFrom('formularz@formularz.pl')
        ->setTo('email@email.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'MainAdminBundle:Msg:index.html.twig'));

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->indexAction($request);

        }
```

And i want to make an form that have: 2 inputs:
- one with current time
- second with current date
- third with someting from entity (it will be select box)

And on click I want to send it to mail.

And my error is: `Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::handleRequest()`

Comment: Get the result of `echo get_class($form);` before handling it.

Comment: Symfony\Component\Form\Form

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using? 2.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you are using a version of Symfony prior to 2.3

http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html
This version of the class is missing that method, although it does use `bindRequest`

http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html
The method `bindRequest` was removed in favour of `handleRequest`.

Switch your `symfony/symfony` version in composer.json to `~2.5`.  It is backwards compatible to `2.3` which is the version you need.